# AJAX loaded php page not letting $_GET's find values

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have a PHP project that I'm using AJAX in to refresh a part of the page, part of that page grabs options from the URL on what it's going to show. On load and refresh this works perfectly. When AJAX is introduced to reload the php file inside of the div, the only part that doesn't work is the $_GET.

I really don't know anything about AJAX and am trying to learn, but can not figure this out for the life of me. And Google searches haven't lead me in the right direction.

AJAX:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery('.ajaxform').submit( function() {

        $.ajax({
            url     : $(this).attr('action'),
            type    : $(this).attr('method'),
            data    : $(this).serialize(),
            success : function( data ) {
              $('#footer-holder').html( data );
              $('#authCheck').load('authentication.php');
                      },
            error   : function(){
                         alert('Something wrong');
                      }
        });

        return false;
    });

});
```

authentication.php has some $_GET commands, the page executes perfectly on refresh and everything else executes perfectly with this AJAX call except the $_GET requests.

Sample authentication.php

```
if(isset($_GET['test'])){
 echo $_GET['test'];
}else{
 echo "nothing in GET";
}
```

Sample index.php

```
echo "<div id='authCheck'>";
include 'authentication.php';
echo "</div>";
```

Comment: can you show the php code? what u have in that

Comment: updated the very simple test I've done, my code has a lot more than this. but this test also fails.

Comment: @AndrewWilson is it a typo mistake? you are missing `{` after else in `authentication.php` and also in index.php ? `echo "</div>;` should be like `echo "</div>";`

Comment: sorry typo, not on the computer with the code. I fixed that. If I refresh the page it all works. It's specially when authentication.php is refreshed through AJAX, PHP doesn't grab the browsers URL.

Comment: "type    : $(this).attr('method')," are you sure about your method type is GET because I can't see any GET param you are sending in URL

Comment: the GET params are on the index.php, will i have to include them on the authentication.php as well?

Comment: Yes. because then only server will come to know that authentication.php request has GET params,

Comment: what's the easiest way to pass that? I have a login/logout form POST that performs the login/logout action and calls this AJAX script. how can I pass a variable through to AJAX from PHP if it exists?

Comment: The variables you're passing as `data` are part of the request payload, they are not appended to the URL. Either you've got to add parameters to the URL, or read the requests payload in PHP instead of GET parameters. Please see if your variables are in php://input: `$request_body = file_get_contents('php://input');`

Comment: the URL params never go into the POST (login/logoff) script. also php://input is empty

Answer (score 1):

If I could understand your question then , you are trying to authenticate user. Using GET method for login is never ever a good way of doing it, even if you are using ajax, 
This may help you

```
   jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery('.ajaxform').submit( function() {

    $.ajax({
        url     : '/authentication.php',
        type    : 'POST',
        data    : $(this).serialize(),
        success : function( data ) {
                     if(data == 'success')
                       //Successfully authenticated
                     } else {
                        console.log('Invalid Credentials')
                     }               
                  },
           error   : function(){
                     alert('Something wrong');
                  }
    });

    return false;
});
```

});

in PHP

```
  //Check username and password, Checking isset POST is not enough for security
  if($_POST['username'] != '' && $POST['password'] != ''){
      //Do you logic to check password id correct or not
      //if true
      //echo success
      //else 
      //echo 'fail'
  }else{
     echo "Invalid credentials";
  }
```

hope this will help you

Comment: I'm not using URLs for the username/password. I'm passing search variables through there and displaying a box saying "you must be logged in to continue" or displaying the correct search box (with options) if the person is logged in. It's an API integration, so the login requests are a 1 or 0 on if they worked via CURL.

Comment: Let me rephrase my question above since I have more information now on how AJAX works.